# Template function: is there a syntax for accepting any argument type, as 'auto' does for lambdas?

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm trying to write a function accepting a complex argument. Let's say it can be a class, or it can be a class template. The code inside the function is the same for all arguments, and I don't need to reference the argument's type anywhere. So, I want to write something like this:

```
auto func(auto& someComplicatedClassInstance) {
   return someComplicatedClassInstance.someMemberFunc();
}
```

I can't just write `template <typename T>` because it won't work if T is a template itself, and `auto` function argument is not a thing in C++. Is making `func` a lambda the only way? It seems odd that the same compiler feature would be enabled for lambdas but not normal functions. And in my specific case, I'm writing an overload for `operator<<` so I can't make it a lambda.

Comment: Could you show an example where it would work for a class template using a lambda, and not using a function template?

Comment: @juanchopanza: I'm not sure what you're asking. Since C++14, lambda's argument type can be declared `auto`. But that doesn't apply to normal functions, template or otherwise.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe But function templates do not require it in the first place... because they're function templates. So the question is, which functionality do you think you can get from a lambda that you can't with a plain old function template? Also, function templates are not "normal functions", because they are not functions. They are function templates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a function template:

```
template <typename T>
auto func(T&& someComplicatedClassInstance) {
   return std::forward<T>(someComplicatedClassInstance).someMemberFunc();
}
```

Comment: Why use an r-val reference?

Comment: @George It isn't an r-value reference in this context. It is a _forwarding reference_, because the function is a template.

Comment: Interesting, thank you. I don't understand how this works, never seen `std::forward` being used for something other than passing function arguments.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe The forwarding reference is tangential here though. I wondered whether to leave it out, to avoid creating a distraction.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe To match `auto &` lambda parameter, you should use `T &`.

Comment: @juanchopanza why do you use std::forward here? AFAIK it is used to avoid unnecessary copies, but there are no copies here. From what I see only diff is that it will call different function in unlikely case that somemMeberFunc has ref qualifier...

Answer (score 2):

Using `auto` in a lambda's parameter list is exactly the same as using a template parameter. It's simply a shorthand notation (in part because, until C++20, you cannot declare lambdas with regular template parameters otherwise). When the compiler generates the functor for the lambda, the `operator()` overload gets a template parameter for each `auto` parameter.

So for non-lambda functions, you have to write it out long-form.